# Auto refresh of box.com tokens failure

Tags: box-api

I am using box.com Java SDK for V2 API. I notice from time to time that the refresh of tokens fail even though it has not been more than 14 days since the refresh_token was obtained. The reason behind why it failed is not surfaced up to the caller.

What do you suggest are the best practices for retrying to refresh the tokens?

Answer (score 0):

When the token get refreshed, the old refresh token and access token is expired.
You'll want to add a OAuthRefreshListener to monitor the refresh events.

`client.addOAuthRefreshListener(new OAuthRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh(IAuthData newAuthData) {
        // TODO: your logic to save the new auth data.
    }
});`

After you exit the application and reenter, you can use the saved auth data to authenticate the client.

Comment: This is good for refreshing the token and persisting to database but if the refresh fails the first time for whatever reason do you have guidelines for retrying the refresh. This is especially important given some of the recent changes to token policy